# SwiftUI's List leaks memory

Tags: memory-management, swiftui

I noticed a problem when playing with SwiftUI's `List`, when I build my row views I create a view model like so:

```swift
struct MyListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(models) { model in
                RowView(viewModel: RowViewModel(model: models))
            }
            .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
    }
}
```

it doesn't matter how big is the list, my view models are never deallocated, I am not sure to which extend the views are actually being recycled, but I can see by using the memory debugger on Xcode that as I scroll and more views are built, more and more view models are allocated and kept in memory, this is how my row view looks like:

```swift
struct RowView: View {
    var viewModel: RowViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(viewModel.title)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

and my view model:

```swift
class RowViewModel {
    private let model: Model
    
    init(model: model) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    var title: String {
        model.title
    }
}
```

I also tried before using `@ObservedObject` but that did not make a difference.

Comment: It's quite different from UIKit where the Views are objects with a reference. There is no recycling, when the model changes the current view is released and a brand new View struct is created to match the current state of things. As you can imagine, new Views are created frequently and also at relatively indeterminate times. So in your code when you allocate a new RowViewModel like that, a new object is created on every View refresh. To persistent objects used by the View across instances, use `@StateObject`. If it's allocated outside the View use `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: thanks you but this doesn't really answer my question, to restate the problem, the view models are never being released, if I create a `@StateObject` in the view, as I scroll down I can see it being deallocated, however, this is not the case when I inject a property in the view's initializer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use @StateObject to help with deallocation. In fact the models' lifecycle shouldn't be related to the View at all. By initializing new models constantly and then wanting them to be released, how would they keep information about state persistent?  Instead try keeping all your Row states in one model class and that would be your StateObject, ObservedObject etc. You can very easily inject any alternate or mock model state that way.

Comment: I know you weren't suggesting that, I was just trying to add more information. The reason I was expecting the view model lifecycle to be associated with the views is I was ignoring that the SwiftUI view instances are not the objects used for rendering on the screen. I was expecting things to work similarly to how with UIKit, where when you reuse a cell you can swap your  view model view a new one. One thing I notice of SwiftUI is that the reuse mechanism is completely transparent to the developer, and all views created on a list remain alive even if they are not being displayed at the moment.

Comment: I will use this information to answer the question myself later, thanks for your comments @CenkBilgen